# A java datastructure which has constant access time and allows duplicates

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates, constant-time

A `HashMap` has constant access time but does not allow duplicates. An `ArrayList` allows duplicates but does not have constant access time.

Is there a data structure in java which allows constant access time and allows duplicates?

I know I could make my own `HashMap` which allows duplicates, but I want to use an already existing data structure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A `HashMap<Key,List<Value>>`?

Comment: Do you need a map or a collection?

Comment: Do you need removals in `O(1)`?

Comment: Yup. It should have all the functions of a Hashmap and it should allow duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList#get` and `ArrayList#set` are actually constant time, as well as a few other functions. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), second paragraph of the class documentation:

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in *constant time*

Your next option would be a multimap. This is a map that stores items in a key/collection manner. The collection holds the values, so a single key map to multiple values. You can look into Apache Common's [`MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) to see if they have an implementation that works for you. Or you could always create your own, simply by defining a collection as the value:

```
Map<String, List<String>> multimap;
```

Comment: The contains query on the ArrayList would take time. That is one usecase I am trying to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Bag](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html) from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), a [Multiset](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), or a [Bag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](https://github.com/apache/commons-collections%E2%80%8B).  A `Bag` is basically a `Map<Key, Integer>` which behaves like a Collection.

All three libraries have Multimaps as well.  A `Multimap` is basically a `Map<Key, Collection<V>>`, where a call to put results in adding to the `Collection<V>` instead of replacing the value at that key.  There are different types of `Multimap` (`List`, `Set`, `Bag`, etc.).

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections